# how to resolve 'this is not defined' when extending EventEmitter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, ecmascript-6

The following code fails:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events'); 

class Foo extends EventEmitter{
    constructor(){
        this.name = 'foo';
    }
    print(){
        this.name = 'hello';
        console.log('world');
    }
}
var f = new Foo();
console.log(f.print());
```

and prints error

```
 this.name = 'foo';
    ^

ReferenceError: this is not defined
```

However when I am not extending EventEmitter it works fine.

Why is this happening and how can I resolve it? 
running nodejs 4.2.1

Comment: you should mark the answer

Answer (score 21):

When you are extending another function, then `super(..)` should be the first expression in your `constructor`. Only then you can use `this`.

```
var EventEmitter = require('events');

class Foo extends EventEmitter {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.name = 'foo';
    }
    print() {
        console.log(this.name);
    }
}

new Foo().print();
// foo
```

It is like this because, the class you are deriving from, should be given a chance to set the variables, before the current class overrides them.

Also, implicitly calling the `super()` means that, we are passing `undefined` to the parameters which are declared in the `constructor` of the parent. That is why it is not done, by default.

Comment: This should be accepted as the correct answer.

Comment: This single answer taught me so much about JS class inheritance.